# Not able to zoom into the graph using eye of 3d scene with orthographic projection

Tags: python, 3d, plotly, plotly-dash

I am new to plotly's dash framework and facing issues with zooming into the 3d scatter plot with orthographic projection.

I tried to zoom into the graph with perspective projection and it worked well.

```py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

def create_plot(projection_type):
    x = [-12.35, -9.05, -15.05, -13.65, -13.65, -14. - 9.9, -14.5, -10.1, -16.95 , -10.3 - 10.1, -10.55, -17.95, -10.85, -11.85, -11.55, -11.6, -13.2, -14.15 , -13.4, -9.95, -16.35, -10.15, -10.35, -15.05, -10.6, -18.5, -11.85, -11.75 , -11.85, -12.1, -12.15, -11.75, -13.7, -11.8]

    y = [4.87, 3.12, 5.92, 5.47, 5.52, 5.67, 3.57, 5.92, 3.67, 6.92, 3.77, 3.77 , 3.92, 7.47, 4.12, 4.52, 4.47, 4.52, 5.27, 5.77, 5.47, 3.57, 6.62, 3.72, 3.82, 6.27, 3.92, 7.82, -0.83, -0.63, -0.78, -0.68, -0.63, -0.63, 0.12, -0.58, 0.17, -0.48, -0.48, 0.32, -0.43, 0.37]

    z = [3.183, -1.517, -2.017, 0.633, 0.633, 1.033, -0.267, 1.783, 0.033, 0.683, 0.333, 0.033, 0.633, 2.133, 1.133, -2.017, 2.133, 2.133, -0.067, 1.383, 4.883, -0.217, -0.117, 0.083, 0.433, 2.633, 0.733, 3.083, 0.483, 0.483, 0.583, 0.933, 0.933, 0.583, -1.167, 0.583]

    plot = go.Scatter3d(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        z=z,
        name='xyz pts',
        mode='markers',
        marker=dict(
            size=2.5,
            opacity=0.9,
            color='#8e001c',
            symbol='circle',
        ),
    )

    layout = go.Layout(
        margin=dict(
            l=0,
            r=0,
            b=0,
            t=0
        ), autosize=True, scene=dict(camera=dict(up=dict(x=0, y=0, z=1), center=dict(x=0, y=0, z=0),
                                                 eye=dict({'x': 0, 'y': 1, 'z': 0}),
                                                 projection=dict(type=projection_type))))

    return dcc.Graph(id="my-graph", figure={"data": [plot], "layout": layout},
                     style={"height": "76vh", "overflow": "hidden", "width": "95vw"})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # app.layout = create_plot(projection_type='perspective')
    app.layout = create_plot(projection_type='orthographic')
    app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

I expect the graph to zoom in/out when I change parameters passed to the eye in the 3d scene object, but it doesn't perform any zoom operation with an orthographic projection.

Comment: Is this the sort of thing you're looking for?  https://codepen.io/MojtabaSamimi/pen/MxaMrJ

Comment: @Rethunk I want to zoom into the graph programmatically for the orthographic view.  In the codepen update the "eye": {"x": 0,"y": 0.1,"z": 0}" and toggle between the perspective and orthographic view. For the perspective view, you will notice that the plot zoom's in and it doesn't work the same for orthographic view.

Comment: Have you tried moving the camera instead of the eye?

Comment: @nicolaskruchten how to do that?